# Adding Variables to a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I needed to add a variable into a Hash. I was trying to do this:

```
actorsChickens = Hash.new
nicolasCage = gets.chomp # is a string
chickenCount = gets.chomp # is a string representing a number (i.e "5")
actorsChickens[#{nicolasCage} => #{chickenCount}]
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to add a variable to a Hash?

Comment: If you want an integer for `chickenCount` use `gets.chomp.to_i`.

Comment: IIRC most Ruby hash tutorials show how to do this; I'm curious where you looked/how you researched.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
your_hash = {}
hash_key = gets.chomp
hash_value = gets.chomp
your_hash[hash_key] = hash_value
```